# Proper way to handle already existed email address for "Google Sign In" in firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

In my app user can sign up through "Email & Password" and "Google" as well. For email, before sign up I get the email list from Auth and notify user about it, either is it already used or not.

But for Google sign in I only can have the email after

`func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?)`

is fired. So imagine if a user sign up by an email address and then try to "Sign In" or "Sign Up" by Google authentication with the same email address, It just replace the existed email list with Google email in Auth. So my question is, is there any way exist to get the email before `didSignInFor`  is fired when user try Google authentication? Or how should I handle this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to know if an email address is being used in Firebase Authentication without calling a `signIn` method.

If that's correct, you can do this by calling the [`fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/Auth#fetchsigninmethodsforemail:completion:).

The logic is that you'll:

1. Ask the user to enter their email address
2. Call `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`
3. If there is an account for that email address, allow them to choose from the provider(s) they used to sign in before.
4. If there is no account for the email address, allow them to sign up with any provider you support.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I was literally waiting for you to come and comment because your solution is allover stack overflow and it is the best in terms of the association of Firebase. Yes, you got me right. And yes I did exactly for email authentication. Call `"fetchSignInMethodsForEmail"` to check the existence. But the problem is when user will do Google Authentication, I can't get the email prior which is associated with user's Google account. So which email will I send to `"fetchSignInMethodsForEmail"` in that case?

Comment: And I checked that say, I authenticated with "xyz@gmail.com" email first and then try to Authenticate again by Google where my google id is the same ("xyz@gmail.com"), it just replace my previous record from Auth list and replace it with new Google status. And later I tried to sign in again with my previously set password, but it says no password is associated with this email, which means Firebase just replace my previous status with google authentication status.

Comment: That second comment is a completely separate issue. Some identity providers are known to be the trusted provider for certain email domains. For example: Google is the trusted provider for gmail.com accounts. So once you sign in with a gmail.com account with a Google provider, it will essentially replace the previous account. If you don't want them, again use `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` to determine if there's another provider and then link the accounts.

Comment: That will be ok. But how could I approach the 1st comment? :(

Comment: I have no ideas there. I guess the user will have to enter their email address, unless the OS allows you to look the valid email addresses up somehow (which I think Android does).

Comment: That’s a bummer. Cause here user will just press the button to fulfil his authentication through Google! Thanks a lot for your suggestion sir. Stay safe and have a nice day.

Comment: Good news Sir. In the latest SDK, firebase added the existing credentials in their `error` message on `Auth.auth().signIn`. :)